# Insert data into a single column but in dictionary format after concatenating few column of data

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, dictionary, pyspark, concatenation

I want to create a single column after concatenating number of columns in a single column but in dictionary format in PySpark.

I have concatenated data into a single column but I am unable to store it in a dictionary format.
Please find the below attached screenshot for more details.
Let me know if need more information.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current situation, you can use [`str_to_map`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#str_to_map)

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([("datatype:0,length:1",)], ['region_validation_check_status'])

df = df.withColumn(
    'region_validation_check_status',
    F.expr("str_to_map(region_validation_check_status, ',')")
)
df.show(truncate=0)
# +------------------------------+
# |region_validation_check_status|
# +------------------------------+
# |{datatype -> 0, length -> 1}  |
# +------------------------------+
```

If you didn't have a string yet, you could do it from column values with [`to_json`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.to_json.html#pyspark.sql.functions.to_json) and [`from_json`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.from_json.html#pyspark.sql.functions.from_json)

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 2), (3, 4)], ['a', 'b'])
df.show()
# +---+---+
# |  a|  b|
# +---+---+
# |  1|  2|
# |  3|  4|
# +---+---+

df = df.select(
    F.from_json(F.to_json(F.struct('a', 'b')), 'map<string, int>')
)
df.show()
# +----------------+
# |         entries|
# +----------------+
# |{a -> 1, b -> 2}|
# |{a -> 3, b -> 4}|
# +----------------+
```